# How to find next occurrence and go back to the beginning of file in Sublime Text

Tags: find, sublime-text

In Google Chrome, when I search for a string and press the "down arrow", if I am at the last string found and click the down arrow again, if goes back to the first string found in the text.

The current behavior is that, once I am at the last string found and continue clicking `Find`, or <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, nothing will happen. If I click "Find Prev", or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, it will go the previous found string, which is the expected behavior,  but, there is no way to do it like Google Chrome does.

Right now, I have to go to line 1, click there and then click "Find", or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, again.

Is there any way to do this in Sublime Text?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Make sure that you tick the *Wrap* option in the find bar.

[image]

Then it'll wrap around even if you keep pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>.